# SSRS Add Hyperlink to Chart Category Groups

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there anyway to add a hyperlink to the category groups of a chart in SSRS (2008)?

[image: Category Group]

Usually I'd go into the properties and and build an expression for the Url Redirect option. I've reviewed the properties of category groups and there isn't an `Action` tab like there is for the values properties.

[image]

If there isn't an 'out of the box' solution, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, you can't make category or series names actionable, but you can make the Series Values (the bars themselves) actionable.

Right click on the field under the "Values" section of the Chart Data context dialogue and select "Series Properties".

On the Action tab, you can then set the Action to "Go to URL". This is the closest you can get to this functionality in SSRS.

EDIT: If you export to Excel, the hyperlinks will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a bit of a pain as there's several series of data and it's probably not realistic to use them in the way I intend.

Comment: Yeah it's a pain. In that situation, you have to copy the URL text expression on each data series... Definitely not optimal for maintainability. Good luck.